# How to make a loop to count the frames of multiple mp4 files using python

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and trying to create a loop that counts the video frames of multiple files. Im not sure how to incorporate the loop into my below code. Any help would be great! Thank you

Code I have written:

```
# importing the module
import glob

video_list = []

for f in glob.glob('C:\\Users\---\Documents\\**\\*.mp4', recursive=True):
        video_list.append(f)
        print(f)

import moviepy
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = VideoFileClip(filename)

# iterating frames
frames = clip.iter_frames()
 
# counter to count the frames
counter = 0
 
# using loop to transverse the frames
for value in frames:
     
    # incrementing the counter
     counter += 1
     
# printing the value of the counter
print("Counter Value ", end = " : ")
print(counter)
           
from datetime import timedelta

FPS = 20.0
frame_count = counter
td = timedelta(seconds=(frame_count / FPS))
```

Comment: Where are you getting `filename` from?

Comment: That was just from the previous code I tried. Im not sure what to put in that line

Comment: No, I mean what is `filename` referring to? Is it an item in the `video_list` list?

Comment: Oh no. It is referring to a general filename that is not connected to the code. You can input the file path there.

Answer (score 0):

Making some small tweaks to your code, mostly to introduce a loop over your `f` list of filenames:

```
    # importing the module
    import glob
    import moviepy
    from moviepy.editor import *
    from datetime import timedelta

    video_list = []

    for f in glob.glob('C:\\Users\---\Documents\\**\\*.mp4', recursive=True):
            video_list.append(f)
            print(f)

    #at this point you have a list called `video_list` that has filenames as entries. 

    #So lots loop through this list and add frame counts to a new list
    framecounts = []
    for filename in f:

            clip = VideoFileClip(filename)

            # iterating frames
            frames = clip.iter_frames()
            
            # counter to count the frames
            counter = 0
            
            # using loop to transverse the frames
            for value in frames:
                    
                    # incrementing the counter
                    counter += 1

            #do your FPS calculations and capture results to a new list
            FPS = 20.0
            frame_count = counter
            td = timedelta(seconds=(frame_count / FPS))
            framecounts.append([f, frame_count, td])

    
    # print out the list
    print(framecounts)
```

There's definitely room for improvement here, like turning `framecounts` into a dictionary instead of a list of lists, but this should get you in the ballpark of how to pull this off without introducing a ton of change into your original code.

Comment: Thank you. I do get an error from this line though: #So lets loop through this list and add frame counts to a new list
framecounts = []
for filename in f:
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename)

Comment: I don't know anything about the library you have pulled in to to analyze a file by filename and get framecount. If you add `print(filename)` just above that line that is erroring and rerun, does it spit out a legit video file?

Comment: No, it wont print anything. Im not sure if I brought any library in to analyze it. I only had VideoFileClip (filename) beacause that is where I would put the path to the file, but I don't want just one file. I have multiple files

Comment: Oh. I see the issue. Change `for filename in f` to `for filename in video_list:` I misread your original code. Essentially we want to loop through your list of video file names that is stored in `video_list` and assign each one to `filename` variable.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting major errors. Not sure what's going on. Thank you though